# Advanced SQL Select and Union Statements

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've seen other similar questions and I have tried implementing many solutions, but to to no avail so far. This specific questions involves a little more complexity. What I need to do is create a table and join columns to the right side depending on certain criterion. It seems simple enough, but there are a few bumps that I am encountering.

The tables are as follows:

```
ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_HEADER

(PK)Transaction_ID | BEMSID | DEVICE | TIMESTAMP | CONFIG_NAME

ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_APPS

(FK)CONFIG_NAME | NUM_DATA_ELEMENTS | DATA_ELEMENT1 | DATA_ELEMENT2 | DATA_ELEMENT3 | DATA_ELEMENT4


ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA

(FK)TRANSACTION_ID | DATA_ELEMENT_NUMBER | DATA
```

I want my final output to look like:

```
TRANSACTION_ID | DEVICE | CONFIG_NAME | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA
```

The "data" column is filled in using the table ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA. The first instance of "data" would be the "data" field in ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA where DATA_ELEMENT_NUMBER = 1. The second instance of "data" would be the "data" field in ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA where DATA_ELEMENT_NUMBER = 2... And so on.

The furthest I have gotten is by using a join statement, except I have nulls in places I do not want them. The code I have used and the results are posted below. So far I only wrote code for the first two columns of data.

```
SELECT 
ADC_Data_Collection_header.BEMSID, 
ADC_Data_Collection_header.DEVICE, 
ADC_Data_Collection_header.CONFIG_NAME, 
null AS locationlabel, 
null AS partno 
/*null AS partno2, 
null AS DE4, 
null AS DE5, 
null AS DE6 */
FROM 
ADC_Data_Collection_header, 
ADC_Data_Collection_apps, 
ADC_Data_Collection_data 
WHERE 
ADC_Data_Collection_header.CONFIG_NAME = 'mobileScanning' 
AND ADC_Data_Collection_header.BEMSID = '2386531' 
AND ADC_Data_Collection_header.CONFIG_NAME = ADC_Data_Collection_apps.CONFIG_NAME 
AND (TO_DATE('7/19/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') <= timestamp AND TO_DATE('7/27/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') >= timestamp) 
AND ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_HEADER.transaction_ID = ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA.Transaction_ID

UNION
SELECT
null as BEMSID, 
null as DEVICE, 
null as CONFIG_NAME,
ADC_Data_Collection_DATA.DATA AS locationlabel, 
null as partno
FROM 
ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA,
ADC_Data_Collection_header, 
ADC_Data_Collection_apps
WHERE 
ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA.DATA_ELEMENT_NUMBER = 3 
AND ADC_Data_Collection_header.CONFIG_NAME = 'mobileScanning' 
AND (TO_DATE('7/19/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') <= timestamp AND TO_DATE('7/27/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') >= timestamp) 
AND ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_HEADER.transaction_ID = ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA.Transaction_ID

UNION
SELECT
null as BEMSID, 
null as DEVICE, 
null as CONFIG_NAME,
null as locationlabel,
ADC_Data_Collection_DATA.DATA AS partno
FROM 
ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA,
ADC_Data_Collection_header, 
ADC_Data_Collection_apps
WHERE 
ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA.DATA_ELEMENT_NUMBER = 4 
AND ADC_Data_Collection_header.CONFIG_NAME = 'mobileScanning' 
AND (TO_DATE('7/19/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') <= timestamp AND TO_DATE('7/27/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') >= timestamp) 
AND ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_HEADER.transaction_ID = ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA.Transaction_ID
```

The result from this appears with null values which I do not want to have.

If you can offer an explicit solution using a join statement or a fix to this union approach, it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe a pivot query is what you need: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:766825833740

Comment: What do you mean "nulls in places?" You can use COALESCE() to change Nulls to whatever you'd like. e,g COALESCE(locationlabel,'NA')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pivot for this:

```
select
    h.transaction_id,
    h.device,
    h.config_name,
    d.data1,
    d.data2,
    d.data3,
    d.data4
from
    ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_HEADER h
    inner join (
      select *
      from ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA
      pivot
      (
          max(data)
          for data_element_number in (1 as data1, 2 as data2, 3 as data3, 4 as data4)
      )
    ) d
        on d.transaction_id = h.transaction_id
where
    (TO_DATE('7/19/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') <= timestamp AND TO_DATE('7/27/2013','MM/DD/YYYY') >= timestamp);
```

I put together an example SQL Fiddle at: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe1c94/9/0

Comment: I tried this out and it looks like a very viable solution, but i simply cannot make heads or tails of this because of my own lack of experience with Pivot tables.

Comment: Actually it took just a little bit of research. I understand it and it works to perfection! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

`UNION` gives you additional rows so it's not the right tool for this situation.

Here's an abbreviated version that uses your `ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA` table only; you should be able to incorporate this into your query:

```
SELECT 
  Transaction_ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Data_Element_Number = 1 THEN Data END) AS Data1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Data_Element_Number = 2 THEN Data END) AS Data2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Data_Element_Number = 3 THEN Data END) AS Data3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Data_Element_Number = 4 THEN Data END) AS Data4
FROM ADC_DATA_COLLECTION_DATA
GROUP BY Transaction_ID
```

This is a fairly common "Pivot Table" hack for Oracle (and MySQL and SQL Server). Oracle also supports [`PIVOT` queries](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) but I'm not that good with them.

Note that once you put your final query together with the `Device` and `Config_Name` columns, you'll need to add those columns to your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This gives me a huge headstart, but there is still one more inaccuracy that needs to be fixed. The max function is only retrieving one value when infact I need all the data elements to be returned. As is stands, i can only ever get 1 record from this query. Is there a way we can pull multiple records?
And for clarification, there are overlaps in the data_element_number in the overall table, but only a single Data_ELement_Number per transaction ID.

Comment: Is the inaccuracy something in my query? Also, please check out the answer from @craig, who unlike me *has* mastered the Oracle `PIVOT` query. Click the link in craig's answer to see and run the query.

Comment: What i think is wrong is the limitation of the max function. My result table can only return the max value of all the data with Data_Element_Number 1. What I want is the data associated with all of the "data_Element_number 1's"